# Shell sorting random float array not working

Tags: c, shell, sorting, segmentation-fault

I  wrote a shell sorting algorithm which works perfectly on integer values, but gives me segmentation fault when trying to sort float numbers. Could you help me with this ? Thank you.

We have a homework at the university and my teacher wrote this program with insert sort and it worked. The homework for us was to rewrite it to shell sort (which I think I did correctly) and maybe expand it further more to sort strings and numbers from files.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

int int_cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2){
    return *(int*)p1 - *(int*)p2;
}

int float_cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2){
    if (*(float*)p1 == *(float*)p2){
        return 0;
    }
    else if (*(float*)p1 < *(float*)p2){
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}    

void shell_sort(void *v, int nr, int size, int(*p_cmp)(const void*, const void*)){
    int i, j;
    void *pv, *pi, *pj;
    pv = malloc(size); //this is where I get segmentation fault

    for (int gap = nr/2; gap > 0; gap/=2){
        for (i = gap; i < nr; ++i){
            for (j = i-gap; j >= 0; j-=gap){
                pi = v; 
                pi = (char*)pi+j*size; 
                pj = (char*)pi+gap*size; 

                if (p_cmp(pi, pj) > 0){
                    memcpy(pv, pi, size);
                    memcpy(pi, pj, size);
                    memcpy(pj, pv, size);
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        free(pv);   
    }

}    

int main(){
    int a[20], n = 20;
    float b[25], m = 25;

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Original integer array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i){
        a[i] = rand() % 100;
        printf("%i ", a[i]);
    }

    printf("Original float array: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < 25; ++j){
        b[j] = (float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX)*50;
        printf("%f ", b[j]);
    }

    shell_sort(a, n, sizeof(int), int_cmp);
    shell_sort(b, m, sizeof(float), float_cmp);

    printf("\nInteger array after sort: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i){
        printf("%i ", a[i]);
    }

    printf("\nFloat array after sort: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < 25; ++j){
        printf("%f ", b[j]);
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: And this is why you change only one thing at a time.

Comment: Good time to lean how to use  the debugger.

Comment: And to learn not to lean too far while using the debugger.

Comment: The debugger told me the segmentation fault.

Comment: This doesn't even compile.  "kul" is undefined.

Comment: kul = gap. Sorry for that.

Comment: main declaration is invalid also.  Please don't post code that does not compile, and expect someone to help you.

Comment: I use Dev C++ and it did compile. I don't know what is the problem on your PC.

Comment: The problem is that `main()` is a valid definition in the K&R (pre-standard) and C89 (the very old standard) versions of C, but is not valid in the old (C99) or current (C11) versions of C.  In C99 and C11, you must specify a return type (and it should be `int`, though Microsoft compilers explicitly document that `void main()` is permitted).  Since you (correctly) do `return 0;` at the end, you need a return type of `int`.  You need to turn on more compiler warnings - or get a better compiler (or code to a more recent C standard than C89 - that's a quarter of a century old later this year!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`free(pv);` move to outside for-loop(after loop).

Comment: Firstly, I can't get there, because there is a problem with the allocation of pv. Secondly, you need to free pv, because you make the switch between pi and pj with the help of pv.

Comment: why `free(pv)` inside loop ?

Comment: @MaXiMkA: The integer sort, which you say is working, does the damage, trampling over the incorrectly freed memory.  When the float sort goes to allocate memory, it suffers from the damage inflicted by the integer sort.  Reverse the order of the sorts (do the float sort before the integer sort); the float sort will (probably) work and the integer sort will (probably) crash.

Comment: ,@MaXiMkA read [free](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) reference.(_if free(ptr) has already been called before, undefined behavior occurs._)

It is not possible to release more than once an area has been  assigned.UB.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: When you switch two numbers, you need a third value which is neutral. If you don't free it ('cause it's a pointer) it will mess it all up.

Comment: OK, thx. I deleted free(pv) and it works. Looks like my logic is not so good at 4 in the morning... :)

Comment: @MaXiMkA no, no. free(pv) is need. There is no need Once **out of the loop**.

Comment: Then why does the program run correctly without any free(pv) ?

Comment: @MaXiMkA Memory usage will only increase even if there is a memory that is not released. It may affect the securing of a new memory, but is not related to the execution of the program itself.